# Get visual studio debug event in VS extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

How do I write an extension to Visual Studio that will run during debug?
I saw kinds of UI or code editor options, but not the software events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTE.Events.[DebuggerEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dispdebuggerevents_event) gives you access to VS debugger events:

```
    events = DTE.Events;
    debuggerEvents = events.DebuggerEvents;
    debuggerEvents.OnEnterRunMode += OnEnterRunMode;
```